# Python-Testing user-defined function but not running properly

Tags: python, function, if-statement

Below is my program...

```
var = raw_input('Please enter a value: ')

def is_positive(var):
    if var > 0:
        return True
    if var <= 0:
        return False

if is_positive(var) == True:
    print "%s is greater than zero." %var
else:
    print "%s is NOT greater than zero." %var
```

When I run the program, the output is...

> Please enter a value: -2
>
> -2 is greater than zero.

Which makes no sense in terms of what I want the function to print. I'm VERY new to programming and cannot understand what I'm missing. Any assistance would be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
def is_positive(var):
    print type(var)
    if var > 0:
        return True
    if var <= 0:
        return False
```

Comment: AHHH *facepalm. Thank you!! Makes much more sense!

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast it as an int and in the method, you have to check `a` not `var`. Furthermore, you can simply `is_positive(a)` as follows. Here is the correct code:

```
var = int(raw_input('Please enter a value: '))

def is_positive(a):
    return a > 0

if is_positive(var):
    print "%s is greater than zero." %var
else:
    print "%s is NOT greater than zero." %var
```

If you don't cast the input as an int, you are comparing the strings which don't compare as you expect

Comment: Hi yes sorry about that, i copied the wrong code and edited it so that var is consistent. unfortunately I have to use the TRUE/FALSE statement. Anyway to keep this and get it to work. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @user3743616, But yes, it is the `int(raw_input(...))` part that is important